# Python3 multithreading socket.send()/socket.recv() doesn't work

Tags: multithreading, sockets, python-3.6

server.py code:

```
import socket
import _thread
import sys

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

s.bind(('x.x.x.x', xxxx))

s.listen(1)

print("Server is running.")

c, a = s.accept()
print('[+] CONNECTED: {}:{} [+]'.format(a[0],a[1]))
c.send(b'[+] CONNECTED [+]\n')

def recv():
    while 1:
        data = c.recv(4096).decode("UTF-8")
        if not data: sys.exit(0)
        print(data)


def send():
    while 1:
        msg = input("Msg: ")
        c.send(msg.encode('UTF-8'))

_thread.start_new_thread(send(), ())
_thread.start_new_thread(recv(), ())

c.close()
s.close()
```

Googling the problem, I think I did it as it is supposed to be. However, it doesn't seem to work.

Either if it was send() or recv() set to be first, I get stuck on one, and it doesn't let the other run. Like I used those functions without threading module.

Anyone to explain where I'm making mistake? I'd appreciate.

(I'm using netcat to connect to the server btw, if that info is of any use)

Comment: `_thread.start_new_thread(send(), ())` doesn't do what you think it should, in particular it can't start a new thread because `send()` goes into an infinite loop. What you probably wanted was `_thread.start_new_thread(send, ())`. Similarly, you probably want `_thread.start_new_thread(recv, ())`

Comment: That is what I did first, and this is the error I got: https://pastebin.com/nmVQSVue so that's why I went with this option.

Comment: I can say with confidence that what you have shown is wrong.

Comment: What is exactly wrong? I provided the exact code I use (where the only thing is changed is host ip and port eg. x.x.x.x:xxxx) and the exact error output with the soultion you provided. What am I showing you that is not as it should be?

Comment: What I'm saying is that `_thread.start_new_thread(send(), ())` is definitely incorrect. That doesn't imply that every other part of your code is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Threading can be complicated, so I'll try and analyze what might be happening. First, in your question you have

```
_thread.start_new_thread(send(), ())
_thread.start_new_thread(recv(), ())
```

That doesn't really make much sense since `send()` is executed and immediately goes into an infinite loop. `_thread.start_new_thread()` expects a function for the first argument, so it makes more sense if these lines were changed to be instead:

```
_thread.start_new_thread(send, ())
_thread.start_new_thread(recv, ())
```

Now lets look at what happens if that code is executed. First, the main thread starts and blocks at

```
c, a = s.accept()
```

until a client connects. Then the main thread proceeds and starts thread 2 running the `send` function and starts thread 3 running the `recv` function. At this point you have 3 threads running: main thread, thread 2, and thread 3. The main thread then immediately closes the sockets `c` and `s`. Concurrently, thread 2 will proceed to the line

```
data = c.recv(4096).decode("UTF-8")
```

It is a race condition as to whether it will read any data before the main thread closes `c`. It would guess that most of the time the main thread will close `c` before thread 2 gets to read from it, and thus c.recv() returns an empty bytes object which causes the `sys.exit(1)` to be called, shutting down the entire program ungracefully.

I'm unsure what you're trying to do here, but the [`threading`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) module is much more useful for exploring multi-threaded python programming.